# customize Help Center Live HLC

Tags: php

I just installed Help Center Live which works fine, but I would like to make just one minor adjustment and after looking almost everywhere I couldn't find the file where the text was listen in.
At the end of each chat the user can request a copy of the transcript. I tested it and it got into the spam folder of my email client. Why, I don't know, but the point here is I would lik to add some text.

After a user finishes a chat session, he or she gets a page hcl/live/chat/end.php with the following text displayed somewhere:
"To e-mail yourself a copy of the transcript, please enter your e-mail address below."
After entering the address and pressing submit there is a confirmation message:
"A copy of the transcript has been sent to your e-mail address."

And I would like to add: "Please check your spam folder if you haven't received your transcript"

How can this be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder lang (where you have installed Help Center Live)
and open the file with the language you have selected for HCL as filename and search for 'sent_transcript'. Behind it you can modify the text as you wish.

As a matter of fact you can modify any other instance/variable you see in this file.